# selecting a member in the generate override member list resharper

Tags: c#, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts

This is a rather frivolous issue, but:

http://puu.sh/iYzV6/958a0dfef6.png

In this menu, there is seemingly no way to select methods other than switching to your mouse. Try it yourself. Am I overlooking something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Space</kbd> to toggle the check boxes.